# How to create a shape with concave side in Android

Tags: android, shapes, rounded-corners

I want to create a shape like the picture below but I don't know how to do that. I searched a lot but I couldn't find the right answer.

[image: Inverted shape]

I can do it with rounded corners but I don't want that.

Here is the code I use for rounded corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"             
        android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use SVG file and convert it to Vector Asset. The result will be like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="359dp"
    android:height="196dp"
    android:viewportWidth="359.5"
    android:viewportHeight="196.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M359.5,196H0V0h359.5V196zM294.25,155.07V40.93h-229c20.5,37.56 20.56,76.26 0,114.15H294.25z"
    android:fillColor="#FFD528"/>
</vector>
```

Save this like (for example) flag.xml in res/drawable and then set it to ImageView as srcCompat (for example):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag"/>
```

Unfortunately this way will not allow you to preserve some regions from straching, so you might want to use [Resizable Bitmaps (9-Patch files)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html) . If you actually want to create mask of some view with this shape, canvas.clipPath(Path) will help you. P.S. ViewOutlineProvider with setConvexPath() is currently not supported for creating masks.